# Cross SQL joins through multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in multiple tables I need to cross join via different attributes to achieve the output. i.e.

| ID | Node |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | G |

| ID | ParentID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |
| 4 | 400 |
| 5 | 500 |
| 6 | 600 |
| 7 | 100 |
| 8 | 200 |
| 9 | 300 |
| 10 | 700 |
| 11 | 800 |
| 12 | 800 |

| ID | Splice Name |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | Irvine |
| 8 | Goodyear |
| 9 | Phoenix |
| 10 | Seattle |
| 11 | Augusta |
| 12 | Atlanta |

Every table has a unique Child ID which corresponds to a Parent ID that is NOT unique. Multiple child IDs can be associated to the same Parent ID (as you can see above, child ID 1 and 7 for instance share Parent ID 100. The ID in each table corresponds with a unique Child ID not shared with any other tables.

What I want to do in my query is have the Nodes show what their Splice Name is. So I want to do select Node, Splice_Name. Expected output for instance would show Node A as having Splice Name Irvine. The example above is only 3 tables and a few rows but I'm working with big data (500 tables and over a million rows)

My question is, how do I write my query to do multiple cross joins? Also my example above is crossing over through one table to get data from another, but how would you cross through multiple tables?

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: Provide the sample data as text in tables, not as image. No one can copy the data from there. If you want to prevent people here must copy such much data and so increase your chances to get an answer, provide a dbfiddle link with your data. You also need to add the expected result as table in your question. Also with text, not as image.

Comment: Converted into tables

Comment: The expected result as table is still missing.

Comment: Thanks all. Unfortunatley this is big data to the tune of over a million rows so with the queries below, its not feasible to write everything out. Is there a shorter query to do?

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to `CROSS JOIN`. Instead, you can use `INNER JOIN`s:

```sql
SELECT n.node, s.splice_name
FROM   (
         relationships rn
         INNER JOIN nodes n
         ON (rn.id = n.id)
       )
       INNER JOIN
       (
         relationships rs
         INNER JOIN splices s
         ON (rs.id = s.id)
       )
       ON (rn.parentid = rs.parentid);
```

*Note: The braces are not required here, I just find they add clarity to the precedence of the joins.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE nodes (ID, Node) As
SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'G' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE relationships (ID, ParentID) AS
SELECT 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 700 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 800 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE splices (ID, Splice_Name) AS
SELECT 7, 'Irvine' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Goodyear' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Phoenix' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Seattle' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Augusta' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Atlanta' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NODE | SPLICE_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| A | Irvine |
| B | Goodyear |
| C | Phoenix |

If you want all the nodes and splices, including those without a corresponding relationship then use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT n.node, s.splice_name
FROM   (
         relationships rn
         INNER JOIN nodes n
         ON (rn.id = n.id)
       )
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       (
         relationships rs
         INNER JOIN splices s
         ON (rs.id = s.id)
       )
       ON (rn.parentid = rs.parentid)
```

Which outputs:

| NODE | SPLICE_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| A | Irvine |
| B | Goodyear |
| C | Phoenix |
| (null) | Seattle |
| (null) | Augusta |
| (null) | Atlanta |
| D | (null) |
| G | (null) |
| E | (null) |

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d905ad/3)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider the solution based on Left Joins.

```sql
WITH
    nodes AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", 'A' "NODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", 'B' "NODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", 'C' "NODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "ID", 'D' "NODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "ID", 'E' "NODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 6 "ID", 'F' "NODE" From Dual 
        ),
    parents AS
        (
            Select 1  "ID", 100 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 2  "ID", 200 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 3  "ID", 300 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 4  "ID", 400 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 5  "ID", 500 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 6  "ID", 600 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 7  "ID", 100 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 8  "ID", 200 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 9  "ID", 300 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 10 "ID", 700 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 11 "ID", 800 "PARENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 12 "ID", 800 "PARENT_ID" From Dual 
        ),
    splices AS
        (
            Select 7  "ID", 'Irwine'   "SPLICE_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 8  "ID", 'Goodyear' "SPLICE_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 9  "ID", 'Phoenix'  "SPLICE_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 10 "ID", 'Seattle'  "SPLICE_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 11 "ID", 'Augusta'  "SPLICE_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 12 "ID", 'Atlanta'  "SPLICE_NAME" From Dual 
        )
Select
    p.PARENT_ID, 
    n.ID "NODE_ID", n.NODE, 
    p.SPLICE_ID, p.ID "ID", 
    CASE WHEN p.SPLICE_ID Is Null Then p.SPLICE_NAME
    ELSE (Select SPLICE_NAME From splices Where ID = p.SPLICE_ID)
    END "SPLICE_NAME"
From
    (
        Select
            p.PARENT_ID, p.ID "ID", 
            p.SPLICE_ID "SPLICE_ID", p.SPLICE_NAME "SPLICE_NM", Max(p.SPLICE_NAME) OVER(Partition By PARENT_ID) "SPLICE_NAME"
        From
            (
                Select p1.PARENT_ID, p1.ID, s1.ID "SPLICE_ID", s1.SPLICE_NAME 
                From parents p1 
                Left Join splices s1 ON(s1.ID = p1.ID)
            )p 
    ) p
Left Join nodes n ON(n.ID = p.ID)
Order By  p.ID
/*
 PARENT_ID    NODE_ID NODE  SPLICE_ID         ID SPLICE_NAME
---------- ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- -----------
       100          1 A                        1 Irwine      
       200          2 B                        2 Goodyear    
       300          3 C                        3 Phoenix     
       400          4 D                        4             
       500          5 E                        5             
       600          6 F                        6             
       100                          7          7 Irwine      
       200                          8          8 Goodyear    
       300                          9          9 Phoenix     
       700                         10         10 Seattle     
       800                         11         11 Augusta     
       800                         12         12 Atlanta  
*/
```

The resulting dataset could be seelected/filtered/grouped/ordered or whatever you want...
**Additionaly**:
if there is another table with node data like here:

```sql
  nodes_2 AS
        (
            Select 7 "ID", 'G' "NODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 8 "ID", 'H' "NODE" From Dual 
        ),
```

... then just change last Left Join to union of nodes and nodes_2 (_3, _4, _n). The same could be done for splices (Left Join in inner query).. and the result would be:

```sql
 PARENT_ID    NODE_ID NODE  SPLICE_ID         ID SPLICE_NAME
---------- ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- -----------
       100          1 A                        1 Irwine      
       200          2 B                        2 Goodyear    
       300          3 C                        3 Phoenix     
       400          4 D                        4             
       500          5 E                        5             
       600          6 F                        6             
       100          7 G             7          7 Irwine      
       200          8 H             8          8 Goodyear    
       300                          9          9 Phoenix     
       700                         10         10 Seattle     
       800                         11         11 Augusta     
       800                         12         12 Atlanta
```